# store payment gateway response on quote and persist to order

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I am writing a magento module for a gateway that authorizes loans as a payment system.

Since there is a relatively high probability the customer will get declined, I chose to implement this using getCheckoutRedirectURL() (placing the loan steps before 'place order' in the checkout flow) so that in the failure case, I can easily return the customer to the payment choice page.

I then do the gateway API call in my redirectAction in my controller.

As a result, I get a URL to open in a lightbox to take the customer through the loan process, as well as some id's from the loan gateway.

I would like to store these additional id's as part of the quote and later copy them to the order when I convert the quote to an order (I did the conversion similar to google checkout - based on a callback from the loan gateway).

However, I cannot figure out how to persist data on the quote.

The obvious way:

```
$quote->setCustId($custId);
$quote->save();
```

doesn't work; the additional data does not get stored in the database and hence is not available in the postback handler to convert quote to order.

The same happens for

```
$quote->setData('custId', $custId);
$quote->save();
```

(and I assume this is just a more explicit form of the first in the sense that it doesn't use the magic setter/getter)

I've seen references to setAdditionalData (for example, [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40484/)) but that looks to be available only on payment objects, which I don't think I have yet on the quote (although I could be wrong ?)

Is there any way to store some fields on an order in the database without having to actually add database fields for them ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add actual columns to `sales_flat_quote` table to store extra variables in quote object.

Since the stuff you are making is related to payment method instead I'd suggest you to store those variables in `additional_information` dataset that is stored to `sales_flat_quote_payment` table as serialised php array and payment methods can set data to this variable as follows:

```
$quote->getPayment()->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation($key, $value);
$order->getPayment()->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation($key, $value);
```

see more from `app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php`

the only downside for this is that it is stored as serialised array at the end which means no direct sql access later if you somehow need to depend on this data, offer filters and such.